# Errno::ENOENT in PhotosController#create - > validating / Minimagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, minimagick

I have a validation method in my Photo Model, which, successfully makes the validation but afterwards when creating the photo gives me a strange error. I've tried to update Minimagick but It doesn't work. I know that without the validation it works correctly...

**The Error**

```
Errno::ENOENT in PhotosController#create
No such file or directory
```

**Line in which the error is**

```
image = MiniMagick::Image.open(photo.path)
```

**Model**

```
 validate :validate_minimum_image_size

  def validate_minimum_image_size
    image = MiniMagick::Image.open(photo.path)
    if image[:width] <= image[:height]
      errors.add :photo, "should be 400x400px minimum!" 
    end
  end
```

*+Crop method**

```
  def crop
    if model.crop_x.present?
      resize_to_limit(800, 500)
      manipulate! do |img|
        x = model.crop_x
        y = model.crop_y
        w = model.crop_w
        h = model.crop_h
        img.crop "#{w}x#{h}+#{x}+#{y}"
        img
      end
    end
  end
```

**EDITED CONTROLLER**

```
    def create
            @photo = Photo.new(photo_params)
            @photo.user = current_user

            if @photo.save
                redirect_to [current_user, @photo], notice: 'El spot se ha subido correctamente!'
            else
                if /(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.match(request.user_agent) || /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.match(request.user_agent[0..3])
                    redirect_to [current_user, @photo], notice: 'El spot se ha subido correctamente!'
                else
                render :crop
            end
        end
    end
```

**Update**

I added the new validation approach in Photo model

```
private 

  def validate_minimum_image_size
    if self.photo_upload_width <= self.photo_upload_height 
      errors.add :photo, "Dimensions of uploaded photo should be not less than 400x400 pixels."
    end
  end
end
```

But now, it's validating. If photo width <= photo height, it will send the photo to crop, otherwise, it will create it without cropping successfully. But there is a problem, when it sends the photo to crop, and I click on create, the following error is raised:

```
NoMethodError in PhotosController#create
undefined method `<=' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (around line #37):
  def validate_minimum_image_size
    if self.photo_upload_width <= self.photo_upload_height 
      errors.add :photo, "Dimensions of uploaded photo should be not less than 400x400 pixels."
    end
  end
```

Comment: The error message means that minimagick cant find the file you are trying to open. Check that it actually exists on the filesystem. Btw, for easier handling of file/image uploads with Rails check out Paperclip or Carrierwave.

Comment: @Sharagoz Im using carrierwave with minimagick... The error is happening when the validation occurs and the photo gets sent to the cropping view, once it's cropped when clicking create minimagick cant find the photo... I so stucked with this. Please help!

Comment: @Sharagoz don't think it's validating

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Carrierwave, try this approach: https://gist.github.com/kirs/1239078

The parts you need to add/change look something like this:

**Model**

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :photo_upload_width, :photo_upload_height
  mount_uploader :photo, PhotoUploader

  validate :validate_minimum_image_size

  private

  def validate_minimum_image_size
    if self.photo_upload_width < 400 || self.photo_upload_height < 400 
      errors.add :photo, "Dimensions of uploaded photo should be not less than 400x400 pixels."
    end
  end
end
```

**Uploader**

```
class PhotoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # for image size validation
  # fetching dimensions in uploader, validating it in model
  before :cache, :capture_size_before_cache # callback, example here: http://goo.gl/9VGHI
  def capture_size_before_cache(new_file) 
    if model.photo_upload_width.nil? || model.photo_upload_height.nil?
      model.photo_upload_width, model.photo_upload_height = `identify -format "%wx %h" #{new_file.path}`.split(/x/).map { |dim| dim.to_i }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Ok I tried this, but, how about Controller? I want to make the create method to render :crop ONLY if image height >= image width, otherwise, CREATE the photo without rendering crop. Any idea? I tried but I don't know if it's validating because I don't know if my controller is OK. See edited question and thanks a lot for your time

Comment: I don't think its validating... :(

Comment: Is the `validate_minimum_image_size` not being run?

Comment: validation is taking place, when image width < image height, its being sent to crop, but once selecting the crop area and clicking on create, this error is shown:NoMethodError in PhotosController#create
undefined method `<=' for nil:NilClass

Comment: That makes me think the image isnt being sent back correctly after cropping. To debug I'd try disabling the validation method and force cropping on every upload. Make sure that works before you worry about only cropping if the image has incorrect dimensions.

Comment: when I disable the validation and force everything to crop, It crops correcty. The problem is that when having the validation the image is not sent after cropping correctly...Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I've put my crop method in the question @Sharagoz